# Vlookup returning incorrect values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-indirect, excel-match

I have this formula =VLOOKUP(D86,'Project Scoring'!D:O, 12, TRUE). For some reason it throws back incorrect values but not always.

I am wondering if there is a better way to do this with index/match? Attached are screenshots to help.[Change Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVot4.png) [Project Scoring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSrss.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TRUE` will give an **approximate** match - it sounds like you want an *exact* match which means passing `FALSE` as the final argument.

If you do in fact mean to use an approximate match, then you need to ensure that your data is ordered in a proper way for the approximate match to work.

---

**EDIT:** Looking at your data, you have multiple values in a single cell where your lookup data is concerned. VLOOKUP is not designed to be used for this purpose. You're best looking at using `INDEX/MATCH` and using a wildcard (`*`) in your match statement. Again, there is a chance that this could also return false positives.

The underlying problem here isn't necessarily down to your "weapon of choice" but rather that your data isn't designed in a way that can be easily processed by formulas because you technically have "one-to-many" relationships between cells. In this case, something like a Pivot table or a "proper" table might be a better design for you to consider.

Comment: This is what I have come up with as far as a INDEX/MATCH: =INDEX('Project Scoring'!O6:O1146, MATCH(D4,'Project Scoring'!O6:O1146,-1)). Definitely seems like I am still getting some false positives. Could you explain how I would use the wild card in this instance?

Comment: =INDEX('Project Scoring'!$O5:$O1145, MATCH(D3&"*",'Project Scoring'!D5:D1145,1)) 

I think this fixed it

Comment: Yes that’s what I meant by using the wildcard. Depending on your data you may still find some false positives but I obviously don’t know your data set well enough. Hopefully that’s got you sorted for now anyway :)

Comment: Yeah seems like I am getting false positives. Do you think there is any other way to accomplish what I am trying to do or where there always be the issue of returned false positives if i have multiple values in one cell?

Comment: You will always have this issue so long as your data is in that format. Best thing to do is restructure your data into a pivot table or similar.